# How to re-direct the user to different web pages based on the input by the user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an index.html page where the user inputs their username and password.  FOr example, i have 3 database table : 
1. CLient
2. Field Worker
3. Company.

I want to have one index.html page where the user inputs the username and password. He/She can be from any one of the database table. Now checking if the the user is from either one of the table, i want to re-direct them to separate pages. For example, if the user is Client, i want to redirect to client.html.

Below is the code:

HTML

```
<script>
function PostData() {


    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End

    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var pid = document.getElementById("pid").value;

    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 


    xhr.open('POST', 'login.php');

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("userid=" + userid + "&pid=" + pid);
    //xhr.send("&pid=" + pid);
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
    <label for="userid">User ID :</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name ="userid" id="userid"  /><br/>
    <label for="pid">Password :</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pid" /><br><br/>



    <div id="div1">
    <input type="button" value ="Login" onClick="PostData()" />
    </div>


</form>
```

PHP

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";

//session_start();
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
  $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
  $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo "公司".'<br/>';
  echo $row['client'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
  echo "第".'<br/>';
  echo '<a href="preview.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you create 3 role and wrap security around your application to change the pages based on the roles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you might want to add a "field" row on your database table to determine the user's field
e.g.

userID | name   | age | field |

a232  | meimei | 22  | Client |

then select the user's field of 'MeiMei' which is 'Client' 
then create a switch statement

```
switch ($userField) {

    case 'Client':
        // code here
        break;
    case 'Field Worker':
        // code here
        break;
    case 'Company':
        // code here
        break;
    default:
        // code to be executed if $user is different from all labels;
}
```

Comment: what if i want to have 3 different databases or is it advisable to add one more field instead of having 3 different tables.

Comment: question: you have 3 different tables or is it really database?

may i know what are your tables?/database?

( i prefer having 4 tables ) 1.user and the rest for your client,company and field ~ 

in users table you have a primary key ( e.g. userID ) then foreign key it to the other table

Comment: I have 3 tables. 1. Client, 2. Field Worker and 3. Company. Now you want me to add one more table users and map them with the rest of the table?

Comment: well this is my opinion and its up to you.

you can also do this:
when the user logs in, check the user on which table he belongs to. but do take note that this will take a lot of query 'power' if your table has big data. which might cause problems in the future and your users must be unique with each table ( this is if you still want to use 3 tables )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE username = userinput` to check if the user exists. Then you can use `header()` to redirect.